# Uniform convergence on sequence of contractions composition

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

Let a sequence $f_k$ where $f_k:\mathbb {R^n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^n}$ and each $f_k$ is a contraction.

Defining $F_k=f_0 \circ ... \circ f_k$ i want to show that $F_k \rightarrow C$ where $C$ is Constant and the convergence is uniform

Proving that $F_k$ converges to a Constant is easy, but i don't know How to show this convergence is uniform

Edit:
I have seen my mistake and accepted the answer, indeed we need the assumption of bounded derivative on each function of sequence otherwise one can play with coefficients

Comment: The convergence need not to be uniform. A counterexample is $f_0(x)=f_1(x)= \cdots = f_k(x)= \dots= \frac{1}{2}x$. $F_k$ converge to the constant function $0$, but clearly they cannot converge uniformly on $\Bbb R^n$, since $F_k$ is not bounded.

Comment: @Crostul well that's odd, do you think any assumption regarding differentiability would suffice?

Comment: I don't think you are correct that $F_{k}$ will converge to a constant. Let $f_{k}(x)=\frac{1}{2}x$ for $k$ odd and $f_{k}(x)=1+\frac{1-x}{2}$ for $k$ even. Then $F_{k}(\frac{6}{5})$ will be alternating between $\frac{3}{5}$ and $\frac{6}{5}$, i.e. $F_{k}$ does not converge pointwise.

Comment: @FlorisClaassens i used the fact that $|F_{k+1}(x)-F_{k+1}(y)| < \lambda|F_k(x)-F_k(y)|$ thus $lim|F_k(x)-F_k(y)|\rightarrow 0$ as $\lambda <1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each nonnegative integer $u$, let
$$a_u=1-\frac{1}{(u+2)^2}$$
and let $f_u:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be defined by
$$f_u(x)=a_u x$$
It's easily seen that each $f_u$ is a contraction.

But for each $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, we have 
\begin{align*}
\lim_{k\to\infty}F_k(x)
&=\lim_{k\to\infty}(f_0\circ\cdots\circ f_k)(x)\\[4pt]
&=\left(\lim_{k\to\infty}\left(\prod_{u=0}^k a_u\right)\right)\!x\\[4pt]
&=\left(\prod_{u=0}^\infty a_u\right)\!x\\[4pt]
&=\left(\prod_{u=0}^\infty \left(1-\frac{1}{(u+2)^2}\right)\right)\!x\\[4pt]
&=\left({\small{\frac{1}{2}}}\right)\!x\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
so $F_k$ does not approach a constant.